# How to get the list of reference libraries of java for the task.json in vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have used "Project Manager For Java" to help me manage the referenced libraries in the project. When I try to use Task in vscode, I don't know how to get the list of all the reference libraries in the "args".
For example, I have such task.json

```json
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "javac",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "javac",
            "args": [
                "-cp",
                "path-to-library/jar1.jar",
                "${workspaceRoot}/*.java"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I can add the jar files one by one, but to how get list of them because I have already added them in the referenced libraries, as a feature of "Project Manager For Java".
[project manager for java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bqd3u.png)
for example in the image, of course I can use "~/Documents/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.38/lib/servlet-api.jar", but it's very inconvenient. So, how to get the list of referenced libraries for "args", just like

```json
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "javac",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "javac",
            "args": [
                "-cp",
                "${library}/*.jar",
                "${workspaceRoot}/*.java"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every referenced library will be showed in settings:

[image]

So you can get the list of them in this setting.

Also according to [predefined variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference), the variable `${workspaceRoot}` was [deprecated](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_why-isnt-workspaceroot-documented) in favor of `${workspaceFolder}` to better align with Multi-root Workspace support.